# Mapping Android platform(AOSP) test types to Soong module types?

Tags: android, android-source, android-testing, android-soong

I'm having some hard time to understand the different Android platform test types and how it maps to the [Soong module types](https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/6282698/linux/latest/view/soong_build.html)

Basically from what I read:

- Local unit test (which runs on local JVM)
- [Instrumented tests](https://source.android.com/compatibility/tests#what_and_how_to_test) (exercise framework APIs via application framework or invoke Android system services via raw binder/IPC proxies directly)
- [Native tests](https://source.android.com/compatibility/tests#what_and_how_to_test) (interact directly with HALs via low-level APIs or IPC interfaces)

How do the Soong test module tests map to the different types of Android platform tests?
E.g.

- `cc_test`, `java_test`, `python_test` etc. seem to be used in many native test modules?
- `cc_test_host`, `java_test_host`, `python_test_host`, I assume those are for local unit tests?
- `android_test`, `android_test_helper_app`, etc.